# Bash script for setting up FTP

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, user-accounts, useradd

Is it possible / any recommendations on writing a shell script to automate the process of creating a new user/ftp user:

Currently the process:

```
sudo useradd -d /ftp-files/user-a -m user-a
sudo passwd user-a
```

The issue is that I need to manually enter the passwords when prompted:

```
Enter new UNIX password: [enter pwd]
Retype new UNIX password: [enter pwd-same]
passwd: password updated successfully
```

With lots of accounts to generate this gets very time consuming.. If I could do it all via a script, that would be great.. But is it possible to input passwords on the fly via a bash script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something along the lines of:

```
sudo useradd -d /ftp-files/$1 -m $1
echo $2 | sudo passwd --stdin $1
```

And then invoke the script like this:

```
./createuser <username> <password>
```

For more information about the `--stdin` flag, you can check `man 1 passwd`.

**EDIT :** Unfortunately, it turns out that the `passwd` command in Ubuntu does not support the `--stdin` flag (at least according to [this man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/passwd.1.html)), so you will have to go with the `chpasswd` option:

```
sudo useradd -d /ftp-files/$1 -m $1
echo "$1:$2" | sudo chpasswd
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - looks what I need.  However, for some reason it keeps throwing.. `chpasswd: unrecognized option '--stdin'` for chpasswd and passwd..? Strange

Comment: It looks like Ubuntu's `passwd` command doesn't support `--stdin`, I added a workaround using `chpasswd`, please check the edited section above.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you probably want to use `chpasswd` rather than `passwd`.  The manpage gives you all the necessary details.  There's also an entertaining read on [why this is a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/078).